# How to debug a Rally 2.0 app.js file when name changes dynamically

Tags: javascript, debugging, rally

I'm finding I can't debug the app.js file locally when testing things out in Chrome.
If I set a breakpoint on a line, when I refresh the filename it's referencing has changed dynamically.

i.e. to something like App.js?_dc=0.1228585853241384

I assume this is some kind of Rally internal setting, how can I disable this so I can actually debug the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the debugger; keyword to trigger a breakpoint directly from your code, or I think you can add the following code at the top of your app right before your Ext.define:

```
 Ext.Loader.setConfig({
     disableCaching: true
 });
```

Comment: debugger is the simplest way it seems, disablecaching didnt work for me.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it disableCaching should be false.  The code example above is backwards.  If you switch it to false does it work?

Comment: Doesn't work either way, I did a bit of reading and there is a lot of suggestions but nothing obvious seems to work.